# Scikit-learn's GridSearchCV with linear kernel svm takes too long

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I took sample code from sklearn website, which is

```
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
        {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]

scores = [('f1', f1_score)]

for score_name, score_func in scores:
    print "# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score_name
    print

    clf = GridSearchCV( SVC(), tuned_parameters, score_func=score_func, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2 )
    clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)

    print "Best parameters set found on development set:"
    print
    print clf.best_estimator_
    print
    print "Grid scores on development set:"

    print
    for params, mean_score, scores in clf.grid_scores_:
        print "%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r" % (
            mean_score, scores.std() / 2, params)
    print

    print "Detailed classification report:"
    print
    print "The model is trained on the full development set."
    print "The scores are computed on the full evaluation set."
    print
    y_true, y_pred = Y_test, clf.predict(X_test)
    print cross_validation.classification_report(y_true, y_pred)
    print
```

X_train is a pandas DataFrame with approx 70 rows.

The output is

```
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.001 ....................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.001 ....................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.001 ....................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.0001 ...................................
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done   1 jobs       | elapsed:    0.0s
[GridSearchCV] ........................... kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] ........................... kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] ........................... kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] .......................... kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.0001 ...................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.0001 ...................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.001 ...................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.001 ...................................
[GridSearchCV] .......................... kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] .......................... kernel=rbf, C=1, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.001 ...................................
[GridSearchCV] .......................... kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] .......................... kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.0001 ..................................
[GridSearchCV] .......................... kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.0001 ..................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.0001 ..................................
[GridSearchCV] ......................... kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.001 ..................................
[GridSearchCV] ......................... kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] ......................... kernel=rbf, C=10, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.001 ..................................
[GridSearchCV] ......................... kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.001 ..................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.0001 .................................
[GridSearchCV] ......................... kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.0001 .................................
[GridSearchCV] ......................... kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.0001 .................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.001 .................................
[GridSearchCV] ........................ kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] ........................ kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.001 .................................
[GridSearchCV] ........................ kernel=rbf, C=100, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] ........................ kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.001 .................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.0001 ................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.0001 ................................
[GridSearchCV] ........................ kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.0001 ................................
[GridSearchCV] ........................ kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] ....................... kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=linear, C=1 ..............................................
[GridSearchCV] ....................... kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=linear, C=1 ..............................................
[GridSearchCV] kernel=linear, C=1 ..............................................
[GridSearchCV] ....................... kernel=rbf, C=1000, gamma=0.0001 -   0.0s
[GridSearchCV] kernel=linear, C=10 .............................................
```

And then it never finishes. I run it on Mac Book Pro with Lion. What do I do wrong?

Comment: If you run with `n_jobs=1` does it finish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed it by normalizing the dataset, like shown here: [normalize-data-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525722/normalize-data-in-pandas), before running grid search.

Comment: Indeed SVC seems to be very sensitive to un-normalized data. Is your data private or can it be made public? If you can share it please report the issue on https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues (just the SVC call with the parameters that trigger the freeze on your data). There is some discussion on the mailing list to add a `max_iter` parameter in libsvm to avoid this problem.

Comment: @fspirit you sir are a genius