# Faster way to remove outliers by group in large pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a relatively large DataFrame object (about a million rows, hundreds of columns), and I'd like to clip outliers in each column by group. By "clip outliers for each column by group" I mean - compute the 5% and 95% quantiles for each column in a group and clip values outside this quantile range.

Here's the setup I'm currently using:

```
def winsorize_series(s):
    q = s.quantile([0.05, 0.95])
    if isinstance(q, pd.Series) and len(q) == 2:
        s[s < q.iloc[0]] = q.iloc[0]
        s[s > q.iloc[1]] = q.iloc[1]
    return s

def winsorize_df(df):
    return df.apply(winsorize_series, axis=0)
```

and then, with my DataFrame called `features` and indexed by `DATE`, I can do

```
grouped = features.groupby(level='DATE')
result = grouped.apply(winsorize_df)
```

This works, except that it's very slow, presumably due to the nested `apply` calls: one on each group, and then one for each column in each group. I tried getting rid of the second `apply` by computing quantiles for all columns at once, but got stuck trying to threshold each column by a different value. Is there a faster way to accomplish this procedure?

Comment: It seems like this question is addressing the tool of Winsorization (which I'm looking for right now) while the related question is removing rows from the data frame. Different questions, imo and linked, but one does not solve the others' problem.

Answer (score 9):

There is a [winsorize function in scipy.stats.mstats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize.html) which you might consider using. Note however, that it returns slightly different values than `winsorize_series`:

```
In [126]: winsorize_series(pd.Series(range(20), dtype='float'))[0]
Out[126]: 0.95000000000000007

In [127]: mstats.winsorize(pd.Series(range(20), dtype='float'), limits=[0.05, 0.05])[0]
Out[127]: 1.0
```

---

Using `mstats.winsorize` instead of `winsorize_series` is maybe (depending on N, M, P) ~1.5x faster:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import mstats

def using_mstats_df(df):
    return df.apply(using_mstats, axis=0)

def using_mstats(s):
    return mstats.winsorize(s, limits=[0.05, 0.05])

N, M, P = 10**5, 10, 10**2
dates = pd.date_range('2001-01-01', periods=N//P, freq='D').repeat(P)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N, M))
                  , index=dates)
df.index.names = ['DATE']
grouped = df.groupby(level='DATE')
```

---

```
In [122]: %timeit result = grouped.apply(winsorize_df)
1 loops, best of 3: 17.8 s per loop

In [123]: %timeit mstats_result = grouped.apply(using_mstats_df)
1 loops, best of 3: 11.2 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good pointer, I didn't realize scipy had a `winsorize` function. However, I presume a more substantial speed up would be achieved if there's a way to do the operation in bulk on the DataFrame without having to operate column by column, similar to how one could standardize or normalize in bulk, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525722/normalize-data-in-pandas

Comment: Are there the same number of dates in each group?

Comment: the group by operation is by date, so each group only has one date. Do you mean to ask whether each group has the same number of rows? The answer to that is no, each date can (and typically does) have a different number of rows.

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask if there were the same number of *rows* in each group. If they were all the same, there might have been a way to reshape the underlying NumPy array so winsorize could be called **once** on the whole array. As it stands, the calculation is slow because winsorize has to be called many times -- once for each group and column.

Comment: @YT As you alluded to in the OP, pandas now has a `.clip()` function that should work for you, especially when combined with `.quantile()`.

Comment: this method does not handle missing values properly, as in it includes them and screws with the percentiles of non-missing data. Using @Zhang18's suggestion is a better choice if you want to exclude missing data

Comment: See this question I just posted, then answered, using clip() and quantile() as suggested by @Zhang18 to handle missing values:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612095/winsorizing-data-by-column-in-pandas-with-nan/50612631#50612631

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution without using scipy.stats.mstats:

```
def clip_series(s, lower, upper):
   clipped = s.clip(lower=s.quantile(lower), upper=s.quantile(upper), axis=1)
   return clipped

# Manage list of features to be winsorized
feature_list = list(features.columns)

for f in feature_list:
   features[f] = clip_series(features[f], 0.05, 0.95)
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Answer (score 6):

I found a rather straightforward way to get this to work, using the transform method in pandas.

```
from scipy.stats import mstats

def winsorize_series(group):
    return mstats.winsorize(group, limits=[lower_lim,upper_lim])

grouped = features.groupby(level='DATE')
result = grouped.transform(winsorize_series)
```

Answer (score 4):

Good way to approach this is with vectorization. And for that, I love to use `np.where`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mstats
import timeit

data = pd.Series(range(20), dtype='float')

def WinsorizeCustom(data):
    quantiles = data.quantile([0.05, 0.95])
    q_05 = quantiles.loc[0.05]
    q_95 = quantiles.loc[0.95]

    out = np.where(data.values <= q_05,q_05, 
                                      np.where(data >= q_95, q_95, data)
                  )
    return out
```

For comparison, I wrapped the function from `scipy` in a function:

```
def WinsorizeStats(data):
    out = mstats.winsorize(data, limits=[0.05, 0.05])
    return out
```

But as you can see, even though my function is pretty fast, its still far from the Scipy implementation:

```
%timeit WinsorizeCustom(data)
#1000 loops, best of 3: 842 µs per loop

%timeit WinsorizeStats(data)
#1000 loops, best of 3: 212 µs per loop
```

If you are interested to read more about speeding up pandas code, I would suggest [Optimization Pandas for speed](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) and [From Python to Numpy](https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/).

Answer (score -1):

There is a 2D array having rows as observations and columns as features.
And, the requirement is omit the complete rows that have any abnormal feature values.

```
data = np.array([[1, 8, 13, 113, 401],
                 [2, 8, 15, 119, 402],
                 [1, 9, 14, 117, 399],
                 [100, 7, 12, 110, 409],
                 [4, 70, 11, 111, 404]
                 ])
```

Is there any APIs or function existing to do so?