# Winsorizing data by column in pandas with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, nan, missing-data

I'd like to winsorize several columns of data in a pandas Data Frame. Each column has some NaN, which affects the winsorization, so they need to be removed. The only way I know how to do this is to remove them for *all* of the data, rather than remove them only column-by-column.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize

# Create Dataframe
N, M, P = 10**5, 4, 10**2
dates = pd.date_range('2001-01-01', periods=N//P, freq='D').repeat(P)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N, M))
                  , index=dates)
df.index.names = ['DATE']
df.columns = ['one','two','three','four']
# Now scale them differently so you can see the winsorization
df['four'] = df['four']*(10**5)
df['three'] = df['three']*(10**2)
df['two'] = df['two']*(10**-1)
df['one'] = df['one']*(10**-4)
# Create NaN
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0).year == 2002,'three'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0).month == 2,'two'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0).month == 1,'one'] = np.nan
```

Here is the baseline distribution:

```
df.quantile([0, 0.01, 0.5, 0.99, 1])
```

output:

```
               one           two      three          four
0.00  2.336618e-10  2.294259e-07   0.002437      2.305353
0.01  9.862626e-07  9.742568e-04   0.975807   1003.814520
0.50  4.975859e-05  4.981049e-02  50.290946  50374.548980
0.99  9.897463e-05  9.898590e-02  98.978263  98991.438985
1.00  9.999983e-05  9.999966e-02  99.996793  99999.437779
```

This is how I'm winsorizing:

```
def using_mstats(s):
    return winsorize(s, limits=[0.01, 0.01])

wins = df.apply(using_mstats, axis=0)
wins.quantile([0, 0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1])
```

Which gives this:

```
Out[356]:
           one       two      three          four
0.00  0.000001  0.001060   1.536882   1003.820149
0.01  0.000001  0.001060   1.536882   1003.820149
0.25  0.000025  0.024975  25.200378  25099.994780
0.50  0.000050  0.049810  50.290946  50374.548980
0.75  0.000075  0.074842  74.794537  75217.343920
0.99  0.000099  0.098986  98.978263  98991.436957
1.00  0.000100  0.100000  99.996793  98991.436957
```

Column `four` is correct because it has no `NaN` but the others are incorrect. The 99th percentile and Max should be the same. The observations counts are identical for both:

```
In [357]: df.count()
Out[357]:
one       90700
two       91600
three     63500
four     100000
dtype: int64

In [358]: wins.count()
Out[358]:
one       90700
two       91600
three     63500
four     100000
dtype: int64
```

This is how I can 'solve' it, but at the cost of losing a lot of my data:

```
wins2 = df.loc[df.notnull().all(axis=1)].apply(using_mstats, axis=0)
wins2.quantile([0, 0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1])
```

Output:

```
Out[360]:
               one       two      three          four
0.00  9.686203e-07  0.000928   0.965702   1005.209503
0.01  9.686203e-07  0.000928   0.965702   1005.209503
0.25  2.486052e-05  0.024829  25.204032  25210.837443
0.50  4.980946e-05  0.049894  50.299004  50622.227179
0.75  7.492750e-05  0.075059  74.837900  75299.906415
0.99  9.895563e-05  0.099014  98.972310  99014.311761
1.00  9.895563e-05  0.099014  98.972310  99014.311761

In [361]: wins2.count()
Out[361]:
one      51700
two      51700
three    51700
four     51700
dtype: int64
```

How can I winsorize the data, by column, that is not NaN, while maintaining the data shape (i.e. not removing rows)?

Answer (score 14):

As often happens, simply creating the MWE helped clarify. I need to use clip() in combination with quantile() as below:

```
df2 = df.clip(lower=df.quantile(0.01), upper=df.quantile(0.99), axis=1)
df2.quantile([0, 0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1])
```

Output:

```
               one       two      three          four
0.00  9.862626e-07  0.000974   0.975807   1003.814520
0.01  9.862666e-07  0.000974   0.975816   1003.820092
0.25  2.485043e-05  0.024975  25.200378  25099.994780
0.50  4.975859e-05  0.049810  50.290946  50374.548980
0.75  7.486737e-05  0.074842  74.794537  75217.343920
0.99  9.897462e-05  0.098986  98.978245  98991.436977
1.00  9.897463e-05  0.098986  98.978263  98991.438985

In [384]: df2.count()
Out[384]:
one       90700
two       91600
three     63500
four     100000
dtype: int64
```

The numbers are different from above because I have maintained all of the data in each column that is not missing (NaN).