# After using scipy.stats.mstats.winsorize to winsorize my sample at 1% and 99%, the Maximum value of my sample still bigger than value at 99%

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy

I want to winsorize my sample at 1% and 99%, thus I used scipy to winsorize my sample. After winsorizing, the max of my sample is crazily bigger than the value at 99% percentiles. I wonder why this is the case? 
My sample is:

```
Total Sales         Assets     Market value 
1000                 123        4892  
1232                 12         NaN
125                  1569       156
```

I used:

```
import scipy.stats as sp

for col in df.columns: 
     sp.mstats.winsorize(df[col], limits=0.01, inplace=True)
```

After winsorizing with my code, I found the maximum value in my sample is still bigger than values at 99%. I think I made some mistake, but I do not know where it is?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the inplace operation. Instead assign the column back:

```
for col in df.columns: 
     df[col] = stats.mstats.winsorize(df[col], limits=0.01)
```

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10000, (500000, 2)))
print(df.describe())
#                   0              1
#count  500000.000000  500000.000000
#mean     4993.512288    5004.678502
#std      2888.254381    2884.128073
#min         1.000000       1.000000
#25%      2486.000000    2513.000000
#50%      4985.000000    5005.000000
#75%      7492.000000    7502.000000
#max      9999.000000    9999.000000

# inpalce doesn't change anything when looping over columns:
for col in df.columns: 
     stats.mstats.winsorize(df[col], limits=0.01, inplace=True)
print(df.describe())
#                   0              1
#count  500000.000000  500000.000000
#mean     4993.512288    5004.678502
#std      2888.254381    2884.128073
#min         1.000000       1.000000
#25%      2486.000000    2513.000000
#50%      4985.000000    5005.000000
#75%      7492.000000    7502.000000
#max      9999.000000    9999.000000

for col in df.columns: 
     df[col] = stats.mstats.winsorize(df[col], limits=0.01)
print(df.describe())
#                   0              1
#count  500000.000000  500000.000000
#mean     4993.505330    5004.690118
#std      2886.521538    2882.414353
#min       101.000000     101.000000
#25%      2486.000000    2513.000000
#50%      4985.000000    5005.000000
#75%      7492.000000    7502.000000
#max      9899.000000    9901.000000
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It doesn't work. I think the problem should be missing value. My last columns contain missing values. Miss values are treated as + infinity, so scipy automatically change the missing values.

Comment: Please, look at this answer. This answer answered my question. Thank you so much.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612095/winsorizing-data-by-column-in-pandas-with-nan