# Winsorize dataframe columns per month while ignoring NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, nan, clip

I have a dataframe with monthly data and the following colums: date, bm and cash

```
date        bm        cash
1981-09-30  0.210308  2.487146
1981-10-31  0.241291  2.897529
1981-11-30  0.221529  2.892758
1981-12-31  0.239002  2.726372
1981-09-30  0.834520  4.387087
1981-10-31  0.800472  4.297658
1981-11-30  0.815778  4.459382
1981-12-31  0.836681  4.895269
```

Now I want to winsorize my data per month while keeping NaN values in the data. I.e. I want to group the data per month and overwrite observations above the 0.99 and below the 0.01 percentile with the 99 percentile and 0.01 percentile respectively. From [Winsorizing data by column in pandas with NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612095/winsorizing-data-by-column-in-pandas-with-nan) I found that I should do this with the "clip" function. My code looks as follows:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index(['date'])
df_grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
cols = df.columns
for c in cols:
    df[c] = df_grouped[c].apply(lambda x: x.clip(lower=x.quantile(0.01), upper=x.quantile(0.99)))
```

I get the following output: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

P.S. I realize that I have not included my required output, but I hope that the required output is clear. Otherwise I can try to put something together.

**Edit:** These solution from @Allolz is already of great help, but it does not work exactly as it is supposed to. Before I run the code from @Allolz I I ran :
`df_in.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='date'))['secured'].quantile([0, 0.01, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1])`

Which returned:

```
date            
1980-01-31  0.00    1.580564e+00
            0.01    1.599805e+00
            0.25    2.388106e+00
            0.50    6.427071e+00
            0.75    1.200685e+01
            0.99    5.133111e+01
            1.00    5.530329e+01
```

After winsorizing I get:

```
date            
1980-01-31  0.00         1.599805
            0.01         1.617123
            0.25         2.388106
            0.50         6.427071
            0.75        12.006854
            0.99        47.756152
            1.00        51.331114
```

It is clear that the new 0.0 and 1.0 quantiles are equal to the original 0.01 and 0.09 quantiles, which is what we would expect. However, the new 0.01 and 0.99 quantiles are not equal to the original 0.01 and 0.99 quantiles where I would expect that these should remain the same. What can cause this and wat could solve it? My hunch is that it might have to do with NaN's in the data, but I'm not sure if that is really the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method which will be faster requires you to create helper columns. We will use `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast columns for the 0.01 and 0.99 quantile (for that Month group) back to the DataFrame and then you can use those Series to clip the original at once. (`clip` will leave `NaN` alone so it satisfies that requirement too). Then if you want, remove the helper columns (I'll leave them in for clariity).

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
import panda as pd

np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='MS', periods=12), N),
                   'val': np.random.normal(1, 0.95, N)})
```

#### Code

```
gp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='date'))['val']

# Assign the lower-bound ('lb') and upper-bound ('ub') for Winsorizing
df['lb'] = gp.transform('quantile', 0.01)
df['ub'] = gp.transform('quantile', 0.99)

# Winsorize
df['val_wins'] = df['val'].clip(upper=df['ub'], lower=df['lb'])
```

#### Output

The majority of rows will not be changed (only those outside of the 1-99th percentile) so we can check the small susbet rows that did change to see it works. You can see rows for the same months have the same bounds and the winsorized value (`'val_wins'`) is properly clipped to the bound it exceeds.

```
df[df['val'] != df['val_wins']]

#           date       val        lb        ub  val_wins
#42   2010-09-01 -1.686566 -1.125862  3.206333 -1.125862
#96   2010-04-01 -1.255322 -1.243975  2.995711 -1.243975
#165  2010-08-01  3.367880 -1.020273  3.332030  3.332030
#172  2010-09-01 -1.813011 -1.125862  3.206333 -1.125862
#398  2010-09-01  3.281198 -1.125862  3.206333  3.206333
#...         ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
#9626 2010-12-01  3.626950 -1.198967  3.249161  3.249161
#9746 2010-11-01  3.472490 -1.259557  3.261329  3.261329
#9762 2010-09-01  3.460467 -1.125862  3.206333  3.206333
#9768 2010-06-01 -1.625013 -1.482529  3.295520 -1.482529
#9854 2010-12-01 -1.475515 -1.198967  3.249161 -1.198967
#
#[214 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your help. Secondly, I encountered some unexpected results with your solution. I edited the question to clarify what the expected and actual outcomes are.

Comment: @t.pellegrom So with finite data (and a small number of observations with each group) the quantiles will need to be interpolated. For instance `pd.Series(range(5)).quantile(0.01)` returns `0.04` (despite the values being `[0,1,2,3,4]` because the default is a linear interpolation. You can try to set the lowerbound to use `interpolation='lower'` and the upper bound to use `interpolation='higher'` when getting the quantiles, then when you get the quantiles of the winsorized Series the lower quantiles will agree if you use `'lower'` and the upper will agree if you use `'higher'`