# Normalizing .csv labelled file using pandas in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I was normalizing the .csv (labelled) and i was following the answer given on this link:

[Normalize data in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525722/normalize-data-in-pandas)

So, my question is how do i preserve labels and normalize the data.

csv file:

```
20376.65    22398.29    4.8 0   1   2394    6.1 89.1    0   4.027   9.377   0.33    0.28    0.36    51364   426372  888388  0   2040696 57.1    21.75   25.27   0   452 1046524 1046524 1
7048.842    8421.754    1.44    0   1   2394    29.14   69.5    0   4.027   9.377   0.33    0.28    0.36    51437.6 426964  684084  0   2040696 57.1    12.15   14.254  3.2 568.8   1046524 1046524 1
3716.89 4927.62 0.12    0   1   2394    26.58   73.32   0   4.027   9.377   0.586   1.056   3.544   51456   427112  633008  0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 1
3716.89 4927.62 0   0   1   2394    17.653333333    82.346666667    0   4.027   9.377   0.8406666667    1.796   5.9346666667    51487.2 427268  481781.6    0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 1
3716.89 4927.62 0   0   1   2394    16.6    83.4    0   4.027   9.377   0.87    1.88    6.18    51492   427292  458516  0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 1
3716.89 4927.62 0   0   1   2394    7.16    92.84   0   4.027   9.377   1.038   2.352   7.212   51492   427292  458516  0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 1
32592.516   2902.4973333    0   0   1   2394    29.326666667    70.673333333    0   4.027   9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51495.466667    427687.2    335095.73333    0   2040696 57.1    30.610666667    12.626666667    3.1333333333    642.2   1046524 1046524 1
37034.92    2590.94 0   0   1   2394    39.34   60.66   0   4.0252666667    9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51496   427748  316108  0   2040696 57.1    33.82   12.8    3   649 1046524 1046524 1
37034.92    2590.94 0   0   1   2394    40.3    59.7    0   4.025   9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51496   427748  316108  0   2040696 57.1    33.82   12.8    3   649 1046524 1046524 1
14433.264   2672.884    0.16    0   1   2394    27.18   72.66   0   4.025   9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51508.8 427978.4    599868  0   2040696 57.1    19.316  12.312  3   649 1046524 1046524 1
7048.842    8421.754    1.44    0   1   2394    29.14   69.5    0   4.027   9.377   0.33    0.28    0.36    51437.6 426964  684084  0   2040696 57.1    12.15   14.254  3.2 568.8   1046524 1046524 0
3716.89 4927.62 0.12    0   1   2394    26.58   73.32   0   4.027   9.377   0.586   1.056   3.544   51456   427112  633008  0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 0
3716.89 4927.62 0   0   1   2394    17.653333333    82.346666667    0   4.027   9.377   0.8406666667    1.796   5.9346666667    51487.2 427268  481781.6    0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 0
3716.89 4927.62 0   0   1   2394    16.6    83.4    0   4.027   9.377   0.87    1.88    6.18    51492   427292  458516  0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 0
3716.89 4927.62 0   0   1   2394    7.16    92.84   0   4.027   9.377   1.038   2.352   7.212   51492   427292  458516  0   2040696 57.1    9.75    11.5    4   598 1046524 1046524 0
32592.516   2902.4973333    0   0   1   2394    29.326666667    70.673333333    0   4.027   9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51495.466667    427687.2    335095.73333    0   2040696 57.1    30.610666667    12.626666667    3.1333333333    642.2   1046524 1046524 0
37034.92    2590.94 0   0   1   2394    39.34   60.66   0   4.0252666667    9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51496   427748  316108  0   2040696 57.1    33.82   12.8    3   649 1046524 1046524 0
37034.92    2590.94 0   0   1   2394    40.3    59.7    0   4.025   9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51496   427748  316108  0   2040696 57.1    33.82   12.8    3   649 1046524 1046524 0
14433.264   2672.884    0.16    0   1   2394    27.18   72.66   0   4.025   9.377   1.08    2.47    7.47    51508.8 427978.4    599868  0   2040696 57.1    19.316  12.312  3   649 1046524 1046524 0
```

output i got:

```
    20376.65    22398.29    4.8 0   1   2394    6.1 89.1    0.0.1   4.027   9.377   0.33    0.28    0.36    51364   426372  888388  0.0.2   2040696 57.1    21.75   25.27   0.0.3   452 1046524 1046524.0.1 1
0   -0.2653633083   0.703280702 0.8672839506                0.0971635486    -0.1327700664       0.3185185167    -inf    -0.7429135802   -0.7470319635   -0.7793509403   -0.659592177    -0.4834384858   0.565758717         -inf    -0.2740463771   0.7057747653    -0.2814814815   -0.5968412303           0.5
1   -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.049382716                0.01991551  -0.0175015088       0.3185185167    -inf    -0.4015802469   -0.3926940639   -0.3315309684   -0.4011652107   -0.3375394322   0.4269561864            -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           0.5
2   -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.1327160494               -0.2494467914   0.2548782941        0.3185185167    -inf    -0.0620246914   -0.0547945205   0.0047090691    0.0370370365    -0.1837539432   0.0159880797            -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           0.5
3   -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.1327160494               -0.2812311406   0.2866626433        0.3185185167    -inf    -0.0229135802   -0.0164383562   0.0392144606    0.1044527669    -0.1600946372   -0.0472377828           -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           0.5
4   -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.1327160494               -0.566083283    0.5715147858        0.3185185167    -inf    0.2010864198    0.199086758 0.1843621399    0.1044527669    -0.1600946372   -0.0472377828           -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           0.5
5   0.5012988863    -0.2432863926   -0.1327160494               0.1027962181    -0.0973647154       0.3185185167    -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.1531419101    0.2294952681    -0.3826408164           -inf    0.492911108 0.1148766778    -0.3481481482   0.3183707398            0.5
6   0.6346322197    -0.296719298    -0.1327160494               0.4049487025    -0.3995171998       -0.5481481333   -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.1606325421    0.2894321767    -0.434241283            -inf    0.6262444414    0.1778154334    -0.4814814815   0.4031587697            0.5
7   0.6346322197    -0.296719298    -0.1327160494               0.433916717 -0.4284852142       -0.6814814833   -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.1606325421    0.2894321767    -0.434241283            -inf    0.6262444414    0.1778154334    -0.4814814815   0.4031587697            0.5
8   -0.0437288959   -0.2826656856   -0.0216049383               0.038020519 -0.0374170187       -0.6814814833   -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.340407823 0.5165615142    0.336895965         -inf    0.0236686208    0.0006186288    -0.4814814815   0.4031587697            0.5
9   -0.2653633083   0.703280702 0.8672839506                0.0971635486    -0.1327700664       0.3185185167    -inf    -0.7429135802   -0.7470319635   -0.7793509403   -0.659592177    -0.4834384858   0.565758717         -inf    -0.2740463771   0.7057747653    -0.2814814815   -0.5968412303           -0.5
10  -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.049382716                0.01991551  -0.0175015088       0.3185185167    -inf    -0.4015802469   -0.3926940639   -0.3315309684   -0.4011652107   -0.3375394322   0.4269561864            -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           -0.5
11  -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.1327160494               -0.2494467914   0.2548782941        0.3185185167    -inf    -0.0620246914   -0.0547945205   0.0047090691    0.0370370365    -0.1837539432   0.0159880797            -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           -0.5
12  -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.1327160494               -0.2812311406   0.2866626433        0.3185185167    -inf    -0.0229135802   -0.0164383562   0.0392144606    0.1044527669    -0.1600946372   -0.0472377828           -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           -0.5
13  -0.3653677803   0.1040274931    -0.1327160494               -0.566083283    0.5715147858        0.3185185167    -inf    0.2010864198    0.199086758 0.1843621399    0.1044527669    -0.1600946372   -0.0472377828           -inf    -0.3737555586   -0.2942252347   0.5185185185    -0.2327514547           -0.5
14  0.5012988863    -0.2432863926   -0.1327160494               0.1027962181    -0.0973647154       0.3185185167    -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.1531419101    0.2294952681    -0.3826408164           -inf    0.492911108 0.1148766778    -0.3481481482   0.3183707398            -0.5
15  0.6346322197    -0.296719298    -0.1327160494               0.4049487025    -0.3995171998       -0.5481481333   -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.1606325421    0.2894321767    -0.434241283            -inf    0.6262444414    0.1778154334    -0.4814814815   0.4031587697            -0.5
16  0.6346322197    -0.296719298    -0.1327160494               0.433916717 -0.4284852142       -0.6814814833   -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.1606325421    0.2894321767    -0.434241283            -inf    0.6262444414    0.1778154334    -0.4814814815   0.4031587697            -0.5
17  -0.0437288959   -0.2826656856   -0.0216049383               0.038020519 -0.0374170187       -0.6814814833   -inf    0.2570864198    0.2529680365    0.2206490597    0.340407823 0.5165615142    0.336895965         -inf    0.0236686208    0.0006186288    -0.4814814815   0.4031587697            -0.5
```

I want the data in 0-1 range preserving the last column(label) as it is.

Code :

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('pooja.csv')
df_norm = (df - df.mean()) / (df.max() - df.min())
df_norm.to_csv('example.csv')
```

I updated my code :

```
import pandas as pd


    df = pd.read_csv('pooja.csv',index_col=False)
    df_norm = (df.ix[:, 1:-1] - df.ix[:, 1:-1].mean()) / (df.ix[:, 1:-1].max() - df.ix[:, 1:-1].min())
    rslt =  pd.concat([df_norm, df.ix[:,-1]], axis=1)
    rslt.to_csv('example.csv',index=False,header=False)
```

Now i get the values in -1 to 1 range thanks!

But now i get empty entries in .csv

csv file:

```
   0.703280701968,0.867283950617,,,,0.0971635485818,-0.132770066385,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.742913580247,-0.74703196347,-0.779350940252,-0.659592176966,-0.483438485804,0.565758716954,,,-inf,-0.274046377081,0.705774765311,-0.281481481478,-0.596841230258,,,1
    0.104027493068,-0.0493827160494,,,,0.0199155099578,-0.0175015087508,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.401580246914,-0.392694063927,-0.331530968381,-0.401165210674,-0.337539432177,0.426956186355,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,1
    0.104027493068,-0.132716049383,,,,-0.2494467914,0.254878294116,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.0620246913541,-0.0547945205479,0.00470906912955,0.0370370365169,-0.183753943218,0.0159880797389,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,1
    0.104027493068,-0.132716049383,,,,-0.281231140616,0.286662643331,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.0229135802474,-0.0164383561644,0.0392144605923,0.104452766854,-0.160094637224,-0.0472377828174,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,1
    0.104027493068,-0.132716049383,,,,-0.566083283042,0.571514785757,,0.318518516666,-inf,0.201086419753,0.199086757991,0.184362139917,0.104452766854,-0.160094637224,-0.0472377828174,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,1
    -0.243286392557,-0.132716049383,,,,0.102796218075,-0.0973647153591,,0.318518516666,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.153141910112,0.229495268139,-0.382640816358,,,-inf,0.492911108046,0.114876677802,-0.348148148178,0.318370739817,,,1
    -0.296719298032,-0.132716049383,,,,0.404948702474,-0.399517199759,,-0.548148133334,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.160632542135,0.289432176656,-0.434241283046,,,-inf,0.626244441365,0.17781543343,-0.481481481478,0.403158769742,,,1
    -0.296719298032,-0.132716049383,,,,0.433916716958,-0.428485214243,,-0.681481483334,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.160632542135,0.289432176656,-0.434241283046,,,-inf,0.626244441365,0.17781543343,-0.481481481478,0.403158769742,,,1
    -0.28266568562,-0.0216049382716,,,,0.0380205190103,-0.0374170187085,,-0.681481483334,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.340407823034,0.516561514196,0.336895965036,,,-inf,0.023668620842,0.000618628782377,-0.481481481478,0.403158769742,,,1
    0.703280701968,0.867283950617,,,,0.0971635485818,-0.132770066385,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.742913580247,-0.74703196347,-0.779350940252,-0.659592176966,-0.483438485804,0.565758716954,,,-inf,-0.274046377081,0.705774765311,-0.281481481478,-0.596841230258,,,0
    0.104027493068,-0.0493827160494,,,,0.0199155099578,-0.0175015087508,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.401580246914,-0.392694063927,-0.331530968381,-0.401165210674,-0.337539432177,0.426956186355,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,0
    0.104027493068,-0.132716049383,,,,-0.2494467914,0.254878294116,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.0620246913541,-0.0547945205479,0.00470906912955,0.0370370365169,-0.183753943218,0.0159880797389,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,0
    0.104027493068,-0.132716049383,,,,-0.281231140616,0.286662643331,,0.318518516666,-inf,-0.0229135802474,-0.0164383561644,0.0392144605923,0.104452766854,-0.160094637224,-0.0472377828174,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,0
    0.104027493068,-0.132716049383,,,,-0.566083283042,0.571514785757,,0.318518516666,-inf,0.201086419753,0.199086757991,0.184362139917,0.104452766854,-0.160094637224,-0.0472377828174,,,-inf,-0.373755558635,-0.294225234689,0.518518518522,-0.232751454697,,,0
    -0.243286392557,-0.132716049383,,,,0.102796218075,-0.0973647153591,,0.318518516666,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.153141910112,0.229495268139,-0.382640816358,,,-inf,0.492911108046,0.114876677802,-0.348148148178,0.318370739817,,,0
    -0.296719298032,-0.132716049383,,,,0.404948702474,-0.399517199759,,-0.548148133334,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.160632542135,0.289432176656,-0.434241283046,,,-inf,0.626244441365,0.17781543343,-0.481481481478,0.403158769742,,,0
    -0.296719298032,-0.132716049383,,,,0.433916716958,-0.428485214243,,-0.681481483334,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.160632542135,0.289432176656,-0.434241283046,,,-inf,0.626244441365,0.17781543343,-0.481481481478,0.403158769742,,,0
    -0.28266568562,-0.0216049382716,,,,0.0380205190103,-0.0374170187085,,-0.681481483334,-inf,0.257086419753,0.25296803653,0.220649059748,0.340407823034,0.516561514196,0.336895965036,,,-inf,0.023668620842,0.000618628782377,-0.481481481478,0.403158769742,,,

0
```

Any suggestion .. :)

Comment: show us what did you try already and what has failed. It would be also helpful if you would post a sample of expected output.

Comment: and what happened to your headers? i hope it's a problem just in this sample data?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df_norm = (df.ix[:, 0:-1] - df.ix[:, 0:-1].mean()) / (df.ix[:, 0:-1].max() - df.ix[:, 0:-1].min())
```

and then add your `label` column:

```
rslt =  pd.concat([df_norm, df.ix[:, -1]], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! It gave me label-preserved  .csv but why i get empty entries in .csv now  i have put updated code and output in question. Hope it may be useful for understanding my problem. :)