# Normalize data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

I would like to normalise this value in the range of 0 to 100. I have these values in a pandas dataframe.

```
    Latitude    Longitude
    25.436596   -100.887300
    25.436596   -100.887700
    25.436493   -100.887421
    25.436570   -100.887344
    25.436596   -100.887321
```

I am able to normalize the data between -1 to 1 using

```
    df_norm1 = (df - df.mean()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

Can I normalise the same data in the range of 0 to 100. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When `df.max()` is equal to `df.min()`, such normalization failed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalize data in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525722/normalize-data-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to:

```
100 * (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

The `(df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())` part is min-max normalization where the new scale is [0, 1]. If you multiply that with 100, you get your desired range.