# Ignore string columns while doing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, normalization

I am using the following code to normalize a pandas DataFrame:

```
df_norm = (df - df.mean()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

This works fine when all columns are numeric. However, now I have some string columns in `df` and the above normalization got errors. Is there a way to perform such normalization only on numeric columns of a data frame (keeping string column unchanged)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to calculate value for the desired columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c': [4, 5, 6]})

df

   a  b  c
0  1  a  4
1  2  b  5
2  3  c  6

df_num = df.select_dtypes(include='number')

df_num

   a  c
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

And then you can assign them back to the original `df`:

```
df_norm = (df_num - df_num.mean()) / (df_num.max() - df_num.min())


df[df_norm.columns] = df_norm

df

     a  b    c
0 -0.5  a -0.5
1  0.0  b  0.0
2  0.5  c  0.5
```

Comment: Didn't see your answer as I was writing mine. Can delete if necessary, not sure what the protocol is.

Comment: look at my answer and address the one deficiency in your answer. Namely that you can cover all numeric types with np.number.