# How to standardize matrix row-wise (axis=1)?

Tags: python, matrix, standardized

For a two-dimensional array, I'm trying to make a standardize-function, which should work row-wise and column-wise. I'm not sure what to do when an argument is given with axis=1 (row-wise).

```
def standardize(x, axis=None):
if axis == 0:
    return (x - x.mean(axis)) / x.std(axis)
else:
    ?????
```

I tried to change `axis` to `axis = 1` in this part: `(x - x.mean(axis)) / x.std(axis)`

But then I got the following error:

```
 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) (4,)
```

Can someone explain to me what to do as I'm still a beginner?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525722/normalize-data-in-pandas, see if you can adapt your code accordingly. It is well illustrated with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error you are seeing is that you cannot calculate

```
x - x.mean(1)
```

because

```
x.shape = (4, 3)
x.mean(1).shape = (4,)  # mean(), sum(), std() etc. remove the dimension they are applied to
```

However, you could do the operation if we could somehow make sure `mean()` **keeps the dimension it is applied to**, resulting in

```
x.mean(1).shape = (4, 1)
```

(look up [NumPy Broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)).

Because this is such a common issue, the NumPy developers introduced a parameter that does exactly that: `keepdims=True`, which you should use in `mean()` and `std()`:

```
def standardize(x, axis=None):
    return (x - x.mean(axis, keepdims=True)) / x.std(axis, keepdims=True)
```